# Pacman for PC does not persist high scores

Tags: pc, pac-man

I used to play this game years ago and I recently found it again, so I decided to try it.

[image]

To my surprise, every time I lose and start another game, the previous score is not persisted, it's back to 0.

[image]

I don't actually remember if it was always like this, or if there is something wrong with this installer/version of the game.

Does anybody know if it's possible for this app to persist the score locally (offline) between game (and app) restarts?

Thanks

EDIT:

I downloaded it from https://qpdownload.com/pacman/

EDIT:

When I played it years ago in Windows XP, the game *did* save the progress in a file called *neavePacman.sol*.

Comment: What version is this? Where did it come from? There are likely so many versions of this game that it will be hard to tell which one this is without more information.

Comment: @Ash sorry, edited. if you need more info, please ask

Answer (score 4):

This isn't the official Pacman, if you want to get the original version, try running the arcade ROM with MAME. The arcade version does save the high scores.

Comment: well, this seems to be helpful but I don't really know where to find *the arcade ROM* nor I know what *MAME* is. I'll keep looking I guess

Comment: well, I just installed MAME and downloaded pacman.zip (rom) and now I know what you meant by *original*. well, I'M ALL FOR CLASSICS (and reading about MAME, I really appreciate what they're doing and I'll keep it) but, I'd really like to be able to save my progress playing the version I posted, its look and feel is way more modern and I'd just like to be able to play it. also, I don't need an emulator for that one, it's just an .exe. thanks though

Answer (score 2):

search in your c: drive using "*.sol" > you will find the location of "**neavePacman.sol**" > the high score recording file

Comment: Hi Vijayanthiran, the question is not where that file is. The OP mentions that file because they re used to the scores being saved in that file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/315419)